# PHP's mail relay via OpenSMTPD returns error Message is not RFC 2822 compliant

Tags: php, smtp, ssmtp, opensmtpd

I have the following setting in my `php.ini`

```
[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Binary `/usr/sbin/sendmail` comes from the installed [ssmtp](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.13/main/x86_64/ssmtp) package on Alpine Linux. I want to relay all emails to the `opensmtpd` container from the private network, so my `/etc/ssmtp.conf` looks like this:

```
mailhub=opensmtpd
```

This is how I send the email:

```
$ php -r 'mail("valid@address.com", "Test subject", "This is our test message", "From: my@email.com");'
```

and I get the following error:

> sendmail: 550 5.7.1 Delivery not authorized, message refused: Message is not RFC 2822 compliant

---

**UPDATE**

Added more verbosity to the `sendmail` command and adjusted a bit the `/etc/ssmtp.conf` as follows:

```
mailhub=opensmtpd:25
FromLineOverride=Yes
UseTLS=No
```

This is how I call it

```
$ php -r '$headers = ["Date" => date("r", time()), "From" => "my@email.com", "Reply-To" => "my@email.com", "X-Mailer" => "PHP/" .
 phpversion()]; mail("valid@email.com", "Test subject", "This is our test masdlkfjaslkdfjaslkdfjaskldjfeproiqweessage\r\n", $headers);'
```

And this is the output:

```
[<-] 220 opensmtpd-2298774033-mq2hl ESMTP OpenSMTPD
[->] HELO php-3107772150-7jj96
[<-] 250 opensmtpd-2298774033-mq2hl Hello php-3107772150-7jj96 [172.17.0.60], pleased to meet you
[->] MAIL FROM:<my@email.com>
[<-] 250 2.0.0: Ok
[->] RCPT TO:<opensmtpd:25@php-3107772150-7jj96>
[<-] 250 2.1.5 Destination address valid: Recipient ok
[->] DATA
[<-] 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
[->] Received: by php-3107772150-7jj96 (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Fri, 01 Apr 2022 14:13:35 +0000
[->] To: valid@email.com
[->] Subject: Test subject
[->] Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2022 14:13:35 +0000
[->] From: my@email.com
[->] Reply-To: my@email.com
[->] X-Mailer: PHP/8.0.17
[->]
[->] This is our test masdlkfjaslkdfjaslkdfjaskldjfeproiqweessage
[->]
[->]
[->] .
[<-] 550 5.7.1 Delivery not authorized, message refused: Message is not RFC 2822 compliant
```

I don't get it

---

**UPDATE 2**

As you can see from the output above the recipient was incorrect, that's because ssmtp's `sendmail` from Alpine package doesn't support `-t` flag. You can of course change `sendmail_path` in php config to `/usr/sbin/ssmtp -t -f` which will set correct recipients but `ssmtp` unfortunately doesn't support `-v` flag which is crucial for me to debug.

I actually made it work for a short time. I've removed `ssmtp` package so `/usr/sbin/sendmail` now used from busybox. That's what I used in the first place, the problem is it can't override FROM email from the message, so you have to hardcode the sender:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f my@email.com -v -S opensmtpd:25
```

Once I did that and prepended my body message with `Body:` it started working and I actually received the email. However, it also included "Body:" in the actual email message which I found weird. I thought perhaps this is a bug in OpenSMTPD, so I updated it from 6.0.3 to 6.7.1. And after that it stopped working again:

```
sendmail: recv:'220 opensmtpd-839025387-f4d7n ESMTP OpenSMTPD'
sendmail: send:'EHLO php-4163283461-9fd2b'
sendmail: recv:'250-opensmtpd-839025387-f4d7n Hello php-4163283461-9fd2b [172.17.0.50], pleased to meet you'
sendmail: recv:'250-8BITMIME'
sendmail: recv:'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES'
sendmail: recv:'250-SIZE 36700160'
sendmail: recv:'250-DSN'
sendmail: recv:'250 HELP'
sendmail: send:'MAIL FROM:<my@email.com>'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.0.0 Ok'
sendmail: send:'RCPT TO:<valid@email.com>'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.1.5 Destination address valid: Recipient ok'
sendmail: send:'DATA'
sendmail: recv:'354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself'
'endmail: send:'To: valid@email.com
'endmail: send:'Subject: Test subject
'endmail: send:'From: my@email.com
'endmail: send:'
'endmail: send:'Body: This is our test message
sendmail: send:''
sendmail: send:'.'
sendmail: recv:'550 5.7.1 Delivery not authorized, message refused: Message is not RFC 2822 compliant'
sendmail: . failed
```

And this is opensmtpd config:

```
listen on 0.0.0.0

table aliases file:/etc/smtpd/aliases

queue ttl 4d

bounce warn-interval 1h, 6h, 2d

smtp max-message-size 35M

table authinfo db:/etc/smtpd/authinfo.db
action act01 relay host "smtp+tls://user@host:587" auth <authinfo>
match from any for any action act01
```

Sending emails directly from OpenSMTPD works like a charm.

Comment: The Received: header looks odd; the format is not strictly specified, but the unpaired parenthesis is a syntax error. Why are you adding a `Received:` header at all? (I'm genuinely just asking; perhaps you have a very good reason.)

Comment: @tripleee I don't add the `Received` header in my php code, probably ssmtp adds it

Comment: Actually I don't think it does, but perhaps your PHP library "helpfully" adds it (shudder). Are you sure the log excerpt is correctly transcribed?

Comment: @tripleee see the "update 2" I've added, that's the verbose output of the busybox's sendmail, no `Received` header here unlike the previous from `ssmtp`, still the same RFC error however. I don't use any libraries, `mail` is the standard built-in php function

Comment: As I pointed out on the now-deleted duplicate, the verbose logging reveals a problem with line feeds. I'm guessing Busybox `sendmail` isn't a real Sendmail, and chokes on DOS line endings, but that's pure speculation.

Comment: Looks like a known bug: https://github.com/OpenSMTPD/OpenSMTPD/issues/1135 ... and sorry for being confused, this apparently comes from OpenSMTPD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tripleee noted in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71706100/phps-mail-relay-via-opensmtpd-returns-error-message-is-not-rfc-2822-compliant?noredirect=1#comment126744836_71706100) it seems this is a [known bug](https://github.com/OpenSMTPD/OpenSMTPD/issues/1135) in OpenSMTPD. I tried adding a CR (`\r`) before the body:

```
$ php -r 'mail("<valid@email.com>", "Test subject", "\rThis is our test message", "From: my@email.com");'
```

And it worked but **only for OpenSMTPD 6.0, not 6.7**:

```
sendmail: recv:'220 opensmtpd-401834694-0hz0r ESMTP OpenSMTPD'
sendmail: send:'EHLO php-4163283461-9fd2b'
sendmail: recv:'250-opensmtpd-401834694-0hz0r Hello php-4163283461-9fd2b [172.17.0.50], pleased to meet you'
sendmail: recv:'250-8BITMIME'
sendmail: recv:'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES'
sendmail: recv:'250-SIZE 36700160'
sendmail: recv:'250-DSN'
sendmail: recv:'250 HELP'
sendmail: send:'MAIL FROM:<my@email.com>'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.0.0: Ok'
sendmail: send:'RCPT TO:<valid@email.com>'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.1.5 Destination address valid: Recipient ok'
sendmail: send:'DATA'
sendmail: recv:'354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself'
'endmail: send:'To: <valid@email.com>
'endmail: send:'Subject: Test subject
'endmail: send:'From: my@email.com
'endmail: send:'
'his is our test message
sendmail: send:''
sendmail: send:'.'
sendmail: recv:'250 2.0.0: 9b837971 Message accepted for delivery'
sendmail: send:'QUIT'
sendmail: recv:'221 2.0.0: Bye'
```

---

**UPDATED**

I found [this issue](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8086) in php repository discussing the same problem with `CRLF` and the suggestion how to fix it that works for all versions of OpenSMTPD:

```
sendmail_path = '/usr/bin/dos2unix -u | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f my@email.com -v -S opensmtpd:25'
```

I'm still not sure what's exactly causing the issues by not following the RFC, it's either php, sendmail (both busybox's and ssmtp's) or OpenSMTPD. But for now I consider the workaround with `dos2unix` as the solution to my issue.

---

**Addition**

This is [the issue](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/7902) reported in php repository saying that headers are not delimited with `CRLF` as it should according to the RFC. And this is [the commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/03816fba46d5db687d27d7cfbd471411b76cf9ee) that fixes it (from what I can tell since 8.1.3 and 8.0.16). So, PHP now uses a correct delimiter `\r\n` but sendmail expects `\n` so looks like it's a sendmail bug after all.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC2822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) says Date: and From: headers are required (section 3.6)

Comment: No, still the same error `php -r '$date=date("r", time()); mail("valid@address.com", "Test subject", "This is our test message", "From: my@email.com\r\nDate: ${date}");'`

Comment: Put From in <my@email.com> and order Date: date("r") \n\rFrom: <my@email.com> also refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.
Then if don't work try tu put in an array

Comment: still doesn't work: `php -r '$headers = ["Date" => date("r", time()), "From" => "my@email.com", "Reply-To" => "my@email.com", "X-Mailer" => "PHP/" .
 phpversion()]; mail("valid@email.com", "Test subject", "This is our test message", $headers);'`

Comment: `\n\r` is completely wrong, and the order of these headers doesn't matter at all.